# UISlider value to string

Tags: objective-c

i am getting error: cannot convert to pointer type

```
NSMutableDictonary *mydictonary;
[mydictionary setValue: [mySlider.value UTF8String] forKey: @"BR"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mySlider.value is a float, which does not respond to UTF8String selector.

Try this:

```
[mydictionary setValue:[[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:mySlider.value] stringValue] UTF8String] forKey: @"BR"];
```

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of 'setValue:forKey:' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: If you just need an NSString stored in your dictionary, take out the "UTF8String" selector and just use "stringValue".

Comment: You shouldn't use `UTF8String`. Dictionary values must be objects, while `-[NSString UTF8String]` returns a `char*`.